# Proving Spanning of a set of Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B=\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $k<n$, then there exists a vector $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\vec{v} \notin Span B$.

This is a practice problem I cannot figure out. I learned the Systems Rank Theorem but I am not sure how it applies here.

Comment: There are many ways to approach this problem. Perhaps it would be better if you can tell what is "systems rank theorem" so that based on that a hint/answer can be given.

Comment: @Anurag If $A$ is a coefficient matrix, and rank$A$=n, then the system is consistent. If the Rank$A$ < Rank$[A|b]$, then the system is consistent.

Comment: Idea: If you consider $A$ as the matrix whose columns are these $k$ vectors, then that matrix is of size $n \times k$. Thus the rank of this matrix cannot be more than $k$. Since $k <n$, this matrix when row reduced will have at least $n-k$ zero rows. Now consider $[A|b]$. If this is row reduced then the coefficient matrix will have at least $n-k$ zero rows, but we can always find a $b$ such that rank$[A|b]$ is bigger than rank$A$.

Comment: @Anurag since the rank of the augmented system is bigger than the rank of the coefficient matrix, then the system is inconsistent. How does this show that there is another vector $\vec{v}$ not in $Span B$?

Comment: The system being inconsistent for some $b$ shows that this $b$ cannot be expressed as a linear combination of the columns of matrix $A$, thereby establishing that columns of $A$ do not span entire $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Alternatively, the subspace spanned by $B$ cannot possibly be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, as there are not n vectors.  For example, if n=3, and k=2, then $B$ spans a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Clearly there are many $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^3 $ that are not on this plane.